# ajaxComplete() not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my code prices.html file is not loading..  I want  prices.html file to load then I want to show thank you at the end.. But it directly showing thank you message.

In this way ajaxComplete() do work?

```
    <script> 
   $(button).click(function){ 
    $(".pricelist").load("prices.html")
      });

          $(document).ajaxComplete(function()
       {
      $(".show").text("thank you for interest");
   }); 
</script>
<body>
 <div class= "pricelist"></div>
 <div class="show"> </div>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more straightforward and direct way to do what you want would be to make use of the `complete` callback argument that [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) supports.

```
$(button).click(function () {
    $(".pricelist").load("prices.html", function () {
        $(".show").text("thank you for interest");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, all ajaxComplete handlers are invoked, regardless of what Ajax request was completed. If you must differentiate between the requests, use the parameters passed to the handler. Try something like this.

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings)
 {
   if ( settings.url === "prices.html" ) {
        $(".show").text("thank you for interest");
   }
 });
```